# How to send in token(Authrization type Bearer token and Header value APIkey as per postman) via axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

In postman we have the tab like Authorization and Header and Authorization have the type
suppose I have Bearer token type in Authorization tab and Header tab have the ApiKey, I want to send these both value via axios. this code include only headers tab value how to include Authorization tab value?

```
const options: any = {
                method: 'GET',
                url: ``,
                headers: { apiKey: auth, Token: token},
            };
```